# Element-wise broadcasting for comparing two NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
import numpy as np

base_array = np.array([-13, -9, -11, -3, -3, -4,   2,  2,
                         2,  5,   7,  7,  8,  7,  12, 11])
```

Suppose I want to know: "how many elements in `base_array` are greater than 4?" This can be done simply by exploiting broadcasting:

```
np.sum(4 < base_array)
```

For which the answer is `7`. Now, suppose instead of comparing to a single value, I want to do this over an array. In other words, for each value `c` in the `comparison_array`, find out how many elements of `base_array` are greater than `c`. If I do this the naive way, it obviously fails because it doesn't know how to broadcast it properly:

```
comparison_array = np.arange(-13, 13)
comparison_result = np.sum(comparison_array < base_array)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#87>", line 1, in <module>
    np.sum(comparison_array < base_array)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (26,) (16,)
```

If I could somehow have each element of `comparison_array` get broadcast to `base_array`'s shape, that would solve this. But I don't know how to do such an "element-wise broadcasting".

Now, I do know I how to implement this for both cases using list comprehension:

```
first = sum([4 < i for i in base_array])
second = [sum([c < i for i in base_array])
          for c in comparison_array]
print(first)
print(second)
```

Output:

```
7
[15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```

But as we all know, this will be orders of magnitude slower than a correctly-vectorized `numpy` implementation on larger arrays. So, how should I do this in `numpy` so that it's fast? Ideally this solution should extend to any kind of operation where broadcasting works, not just greater-than or less-than in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add a dimension to the comparison array, so that the comparison is "stretched" across all values along the new dimension.

```
>>> np.sum(comparison_array[:, None] < base_array)
228
```

This is the fundamental principle with [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), and works for all kinds of operations.

If you need the sum done along an axis, you just specify the axis along which you want to sum after the comparison.

```
>>> np.sum(comparison_array[:, None] < base_array, axis=1)
array([15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  7,  7,
        7,  6,  6,  3,  2,  2,  2,  1,  0])
```

Comment: I need the answer to be of the same shape as `comparison_array`, like what the list-comprehension gave.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to transpose one of the arrays for broadcasting to work correctly. When you broadcast two arrays together, the dimensions are lined up and any unit dimensions are effectively expanded to the non-unit size that they match. So two arrays of size `(16, 1)` (the original array) and `(1, 26)` (the comparison array) would broadcast to `(16, 26)`.

Don't forget to sum across the dimension of size 16:

```
(base_array[:, None] > comparison_array).sum(axis=1)
```

`None` in a slice is equivalent to `np.newaxis`: it's one of many ways to insert a new unit dimension at the specified index. The reason that you don't need to do `comparison_array[None, :]` is that broadcasting lines up the highest dimensions, and fills in the lowest with ones automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with focus on memory efficiency and hence performance -

```
def get_comparative_sum(base_array, comparison_array):
    n = len(base_array)
    base_array_sorted = np.sort(base_array)
    idx = np.searchsorted(base_array_sorted, comparison_array, 'right')
    idx[idx==n] = n-1
    return n - idx - (base_array_sorted[idx] == comparison_array)
```

Timings -

```
In [40]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: base_array = np.random.randint(-1000,1000,(10000))
    ...: comparison_array = np.random.randint(-1000,1000,(20000))

# @miradulo's soln
In [41]: %timeit np.sum(comparison_array[:, None] < base_array, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 386 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit get_comparative_sum(base_array, comparison_array)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop
```